# How to Get the last element in Array list of Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ngrx

This function is to filter an observable off all message from my friend list (onlineUserModel) and to get an observable of type string; **lastMessage** of each friend

```
getLastMessage(onlineUserModel : OnlineUserModel): Observable<string>{
    var messagesFriend= this.allDirectMessages$.pipe(map(x => x.filter(f=>f.fromOnlineUser.userName==onlineUserModel.userName)));
    this.lastMessage$ = czt.pipe(map(last()))
    return ...;
  }
```

lastMessage is Obserbable of string from DirectMessage.messageModel.content;
it is a string because if the message is a picture or voice i create a standard message; you have recieved a picture or ...

```
lastMessage$ : Observable<string>
allDirectMessages$ : Observable<DirectMessage[]>
```

```
 <ul
              class="user-list mt-2"
              *ngFor="let onlineusermodel of onlineUsersModel$ | async"
              (click)="
                selectChat(onlineusermodel);
                removeNotificationForUser(onlineusermodel)
              "
            >
              <li class="user-list-item">
                <div class="avatar avatar-online">
                  <img
                    [src]="onlineusermodel.profilePic"
                    class="rounded-circle"
                    alt="image"
                  />
                </div>

                <div class="users-list-body">
                  <div>
                    <h5>
                      {{ onlineusermodel.userName }}
                    </h5>
                    <p>getLastMessage(onlineUserModel)</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="last-chat-time">
                    <small class="text-muted">05 min</small>
                    <div
                      *ngIf="{
                        count: getUserNotification(onlineusermodel) | async
                      } as data"
                    >
                      <div class="new-message-count" *ngIf="data.count > 0">
                        {{ data.count }}
                        <!-- {{ getUserNotification(onlineusermodel) | async }} -->
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

this is  DirectMessage which contain fromOnlineUser

```
import { MessageViewModel } from "./messageViewModel";
import { OnlineUserModel } from "./onlineUserModel";
export class DirectMessage {
  public fromOnlineUser: OnlineUserModel | null = {
    userName: "",
    email: "",
    firstname: "",
    profilePic: "",
    isProfileComplete: "",
    isActive: "",
  };
  public messages = "";

  public messageModel: MessageViewModel = {
    content: "",
    timestamp: "",
    from: null,
    to: null,
    avatar: "",
    attachement: "",
    fileSize: "",
    fileNameSaved: "",
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they `this.allDirectMessages$` emits an array of all dms in chronological order, I would think all you would need would be:

```
getLastMessage$({ userName }: OnlineUserModel) {
  return this.allDirectMessages$.pipe(
    map<DirectMessage[], DirectMessage>((dms: DirectMessage[]) => {
      const index: number = dms.lastIndexOf(
        ({fromOnlineUser}: DirectMessage) => fromOnlineUser.userName === userName
      );
      if (index === -1) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return dms[index];
      }
    }),
    map<DirectMessage, string>(this. getMsgFromDirectMsg)
  );
}
```

... assuming `this.allDirectMessages$` always completes. If it doesn't complete then the returned observable should also pipe `takeUntil(this.destroy$)` where `destroy$` is a private `Subject<void>` and there's an ngOnDestroy of

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  const d$ = this.destroy$;
  if (d$) {
    d$.next();
    d$.complete();
  }
}
```

Also, I couldn't tell how to get an actual string from a `Directmessage`, so I don't know what `this.getMsgFromDirectMsg` should look like.

Comment: I can't understand exactly how nondestroy works, can you more explain ...and you

Comment: Assuming your class is a service or component, ngOnDestroy (if defined) will be called when Angular no longer needs that instance any more. See  https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks. By setting up your observables to complete as soon as a particular subject (that I usually give the name `destroy$`) emits, we don't have to manage subscriptions. As long as you let the async pipe do it and don't do any subscribing anyway, I guess it's just safety but not needed.

Comment: there is problem :  Type '([{ fromOnlineUser }]: [{ fromOnlineUser: any; }]) => boolean' is missing the following properties from type 'DirectMessage': fromOnlineUser, messages, messageModelts(2345)

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong, but after looking I realized that my original code was supposed to return a DirectMessage, not a string. I edited my answer to be more explicit on the types I was expecting so that you can troubleshoot more easily. Maybe `fromOnlineUser` is a method, not a property, so the code should instead say `fromOnlineUser()`?

Comment: I would like to return the content of messageModel 'Content' after make a test on its type, that's why. But you can see above i added the DirectMessage class in my sheet.

Comment: this problem persist :  Argument of type '({ fromOnlineUser }: DirectMessage) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DirectMessage'.
  Type '({ fromOnlineUser }: DirectMessage) => boolean' is missing the following properties from type 'DirectMessage': fromOnlineUser, messages, messageModelts(2345)

Comment: Odd. I thought that would surface the issue. I'll look later today.

Comment: I didn't find FindLastIndexOf, just there is lastIndexOf, the I will wait for your answer... thank you....

Comment: Ugh! Glad you noticed. I've corrected my answer accordingly.